# Swift - Adjusting fontSize to fit the width of the layout (programmatically)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fonts

I've been looking for something to dynamically adjust my `fontSize` to fit the width of my layout box. But all the answers I can find, is either to use this:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Which does work. But only if I don't have `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `false`.

Please note that I don't use storyboards. So to have full control over my other constraints I need this line:

```
label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

So how can I adjust the font size to fit the width without using storyboard and when I can't use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`.

After I figure out how to adjust the font size to fit the width. I also need to adjust the height of the layout box to fit the font size. There seems to be documentation on that though, but if you happen to know the answer of this as well, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try the following commands for your label:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
```

And try to change the lines of the label to 0 and 1 (check both cases):

```
label.numberOfLines = 0 // or 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use "label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true"

cause I use programmatic constraints and thus I need the following line

label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

which seems to break adjustFontSizeToFitWith.

I tried both your scenarios, unfortunately without luck.

Thanks for the reply though! I appreciate it.

Comment: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` does nothing, useless. The only function it has is reducing text if it is bigger than container's width

Comment: Because of the lack of reputation, I add a response to the comment of user25.
if you want to resize the font so that it fits the content, you can do something like this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (50.0 is the font size set in storyboard in my case.) if let tw = totalWidth, tw < safeAreaWidth { let fontSize: CGFloat = 50.0 * safeAreaWidth / tw hourLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Menlo-Bold", size: fontSize) }

Answer (score 20):

`MinimumScaleFactor` range is 0 to 1. So we are setting the `MinimumScaleFactor` with respect to our font size as follows

**Objective C**

```
[lb setMinimumScaleFactor:10.0/[UIFont labelFontSize]];
lb.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
lb.minimumScaleFactor = 10/UIFont.labelFontSize
lb.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: Please explain how it works,that would be nice if you are

Comment: Why take 10 in the example?

Comment: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` does nothing, useless. The only function it has is reducing text if it is bigger than container's width

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this will completely answer your question, but you can use this extension to calculate your own font sizes to fit.

Swift 3

```
extension String {
   func height(constrainedBy width: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
       let constraintSize = CGSize(width: width, height: .max)
       let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

       return boundingBox.height
   }

   func width(constrainedBy height: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
       let constrainedSize = CGSize(width: .max, height: height)
       let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constrainedSize, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

       return boundingBox.width
   }
}
```

**Update - Adds example and updates code to Swift 5**

Swift 5

```
extension String {
    func height(constrainedBy width: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }

    func width(constrainedBy height: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constrainedRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constrainedRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.width
    }
}
```

Here is my logic to make sure that two different labels had the same font size. In my case it was two labels for the user's first and last name. The reason I needed two labels for this, is because each label is independently animated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
      ...

      func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         fixFontSizes()
         ...
      }

      func fixFontSizes() {
         let leadingMargin = self.leadingContainerConstraint.constant
         let trailingMargin = self.trailingContainerConstraint.constant
         let maxLabelWidth = self.view.bounds.width - leadingMargin - trailingMargin

         let firstName = self.firstNameLabel.text ?? ""
         let lastName = self.lastNameLabel.text ?? ""

         let firstNameWidth = firstName.width(constrainedBy: self.container.bounds.height, with: self.firstNameLabel.font)
         let lastNameWidth = lastName.width(constrainedBy: self.container.bounds.height, with: self.lastNameLabel.font)

         let largestLabelWidth = max(firstNameWidth, lastNameWidth)
         guard largestLabelWidth > maxLabelWidth else { return }

         let largestTextSize = max(self.firstNameLabel.font.pointSize, self.lastNameLabel.font.pointSize)

         let labelToScreenWidthRatio = largestLabelWidth / maxLabelWidth
         let calculatedMaxTextSize = floor(largestTextSize / labelToScreenWidthRatio)

         self.firstNameLabel.font = self.firstNameLabel.font.withSize(calculatedMaxTextSize)
         self.lastNameLabel.font = self.lastNameLabel.font.withSize(calculatedMaxTextSize)
      }


}
```

Comment: How do you use this though?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I updated my answer with an example. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

I just did that you needed , Works perfectly ! (Programmatically ONLY) -
We are setting large font size to the label , in order to re-scale it to the perfect font size.

```
self.label.font = UIFont(name: "Heiti TC", size: 60)
self.label.numberOfLines = 0
self.label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
self.label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
self.label.textAlignment  = .center
```

If you are using AutoLayout, implement this code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (after the layout has been laid out).

Yours, Roi

Comment: I am using programmatic constraints and just setting .numberOfLines to 0 made .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth start working again. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 conversion of above:

```
extension String
{
    func height(constrainedBy width: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat
    {
        let constraintSize = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }

    func width(constrainedBy height: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat
    {
        let constrainedSize = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constrainedSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.width
    }
}
```

Swift 5

```
extension String
{
    func height(constrainedBy width: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat
    {
        let constraintSize = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }

    func width(constrainedBy height: CGFloat, with font: UIFont) -> CGFloat
    {
        let constrainedSize = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constrainedSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.width
    }
}
```

Comment: any explanation how to use?

Comment: Agreed how do you use this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack solution:

```
var size: CGFloat = 20

    while titleLabel.frame.width > containerView.frame.width {

        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size)
        titleLabel.sizeToFit()
        size -= 1

    }
```